# Need to format user selection on a Ng Bootstrap tpeahead (not resultFormatter)

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using a ngBootstrap typeahead to select a person within the result list. Each result (which is an object coming from an api) is formatted in the list to be Name + id using resultFormatter input, but after I click any result, the text field is populated with [Object][Object], and I need to be the user ID, which is a field of the object

I've tried to override the control with the selectItem event, but it seems like the field is override by the ngBootstrap control after that.

Can anyone give a hand with this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `[inputFormatter]`.

See https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#template

Comment: One more question, maybe you know... I am using this typeahead inside of an angular reactive form, what else should I do so the form control store the displayed text and not the entire object?